# DIfferentiating between "do" "does" and "did"

Tags: questions

I have difficulties using *do*, *does* and *did* for interrogative phrases.

In this phrase,

> Does anyone of you speaks fluently English?

I want to ask if someone inside a group of people speak fluently English. Or would it be,

> Do anyone of you speak English fluently?

Which one is better? How do I ask?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A matrix of issues

Correct versions

> Does anyone of you speak fluent English?
>
> Do any of you speak English fluently?

Answer (score 3):

"Does" is singular and "do" is plural. This applies whether it's a statement or a question. So, "Bob does speak English." "Does Bob speak English?" "Bob and Alice do speak English." "Do Bob and Alice speak English?"

"Anyone" is singular, so "Does anyone speak English?" "Any" is plural, so "Do any of you speak English?"

Also note that "speaks" is singular and "speak" is plural. But when combined with "do" or "does", we always say "speak", not "speaks". So "Bob speaks English" but "Bob does speak English". I guess you have to think of the verb as "does speak", as a unit.